# relayStylePagination in inMemoryCache problem when using the same Query multiple times Apollo3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

So, I am using the same query in 2 places.
In one place I want to get more results on scroll in the search component and because relayStylePagination does read and merge I get the wanted result.

```
    const cache = new InMemoryCache({
     typePolicies: {
      Query: {
       fields: {
        users: relayStylePagination(),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

But I am using the same Query to get users in a paginated list with 15 results and on click on number 2 page I want another 15 results but instead I get 30 because they get merged.

Has anyone had the same problem and what are some possible solutions?
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing an offset which would require a different query to accomplish this: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/offset-based

This way you can provide the amount of already-queried results and only return the limited quantity needed.